# Solution for Discord bot SSL Certificate error (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I am at my wits end trying to solve this issue. I've built my second discord bot and I'm getting what seems to be a common error with SSL certificates.

I've tried to

- Re install certifi
- Run certificates.command in my Python directory

Below is the traceback.

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nullzero/Documents/python-projects/gpt-projects/discord-midmate/bot.py", line 74, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 624, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/nullzero/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 982, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
```

Does anyone else have a solution they've found that works?

I've tried to

- Re install certifi
- Run certificates.command in my Python directory

There was no change in the output.

Comment: try `curl -v https://discord.com -I` to see if that is a local machine issue

Comment: I actually just ran it in one of my Ubuntu VM's and it worked first time. Seems to be a Mac issue?

Comment: seems the OS level issue